# Forgetting to add close() when writing an array to file with Java's PrintWriter, the last part of the array will be left out. Why is that?

Tags: java, arrays, printwriter

I noticed something I wasn't aware of when writing an array to file using Java's PrintWriter class. When I forgot to add close() in the end, the last elements of the array weren't printed to the file. Why is that?

**Snippets from code:**

```
...
PrintWriter f;
try {
    f = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // array consists of 5000+ birthnames
        f.println(array[i]);
    }
    f.close(); // Last elements of array will not be printed to out.txt if this line is removed
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps they were being buffered and so not yet flushed to disk

Comment: Show some relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
close()
```

method will close the stream of data, and flushes any data that remains in the pipe to the output. So if you dont call the `close()` method, the flush is not happening, and the resource is still locked. After the `GC` runs, it might find the unclosed streams, and it will close it abruptly where you dont have a mechanism to flush the data to output( there is no output!)

Comment: Thank you for this clarifying answer, Krishnanunni. It seemed so strange. I haven't experienced this before when forgetting to close the printwriter. I guess "might find", as you point out, is the cue in this case.